# React seems to only allow the event listener prop name to be same as the function name when passing that function to the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My understanding is that I can choose any **prop** name I want when passing a `function` to a *custom child **component***. It appears however that when I am registering the `event listener`, React seems to *only* *allow* me to name the prop *the same* as the function name I am passing in: (click on the picture to view it at 100% resolution)

[image]

`Questions:`

- Has anyone else come across this?
- Does anyone have any input as to why this might happen?

`Edit:`
Here is a screen shot of my **console** showing that the event listener function is getting passed in to the child component:

[image]

Comment: What does the div onClick use?  if it says `onClick = {props.toggle}`, then you have to include a `toggle` property wherever you are creating `<Box2>` elements.

Comment: @James - it appears that when creating a custom component like ```<Box2>```, simply adding an ```onClick``` attribute does not quite register as an event listener. That's why I tried ```handleClick``` and ```handle``` but those did not work either.

Comment: There's no auto-assigning of event listeners, it's whatever code you write that does it.  So in the case of Box2, the onClick assignment is assigning the event listener to `props.somethingICannotSee` (assuming it's props.toggle) so if there is no toggle property passed in, it's going to fail (as you noticed).

Comment: Thanks @James! As far as the blurry pictures go - if you hover over them - your mouse will turn into a cursor allowing you to click on them which will trigger a full resolution view of each pic.

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that I can choose any prop name I want when passing a function to a custom child component

No. It is when you are **writing** a component that you can define any prop name it will accept.

The component defined in *Box2.js* only pays attention to a prop named `toggle`.

When passing a function to an instance of that component, you must use the prop name that the component expects. You can't use any name at this point. *Box2* expects `toggle` so that is is the prop you must assign a value to.

It doesn't matter how you determine the value you pass to that prop.

```
<Box toggle={someLocalVariableName}> ... </Box>
```

or

```
<Box toggle={() => { /* a literal function */ }}> ... </Box>
```

Comment: Quentin thank you for your response. Also thank you for pointing out that I should not be posting pictures of code - I was not aware of it - not going to happen again.